# how to change Android TextView Drawable in appwidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an Android AppWidget which uses a Drawable on the left side of the textview. I'd like to update that Drawable with a different image at certain times but don't see a way to do that using RemoveViews.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean using drawableLeft on a RemoteView, I don't think there is a way.

You would need to modify your layout and make the image a separate object, for example use an ImageView and place it next to the TextView.

Then call...

```
remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageViewId, myBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out a way to do it either so just did away with the compoundDrawable and used an ImageView next to the textview widget.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from API 16 you can use `remoteView.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(int, int, int, int);` but it accepts only drawables from resources and not bitmaps.

Comment: This should be the right answer, given that the original answer was from 2013